# Почему алгоритм на Java 9 выполняется в два раза быстрее чем на C++?

Tags: java, c++

Начал изучать C++. Решил переписать программу, которую раньше написал на Java. Ожидал, что время выполнения на C++ будет меньше, однако по факту оказалось в два раза больше. Почему так происходит?
Алгоритм последовательно перебирает варианты чисел, каждый раз запрашивая функцию, которая проверяет, совпадает ли подобранное число с введенным пользователем.

```
for (int i = 10; i < 100000000; i = i * 10) {
    for (int q = 1; q < i; q++) {
        string str = to_string(q);
        if (getRight(str)) {
            return str;
        }
        string n_str = "-" + str;
        if (getRight(n_str)) {
            return n_str;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
bool getRight(string pass) {
    if (pass == password) {
        count++;
        return true;
    }
    count++;
    return false;
}

string bruteforce() {
    clock_t time;
    time = clock();
    string num = number_bruteforce();
    if (num != "0") {
        time = clock() - time;
        cout << "program running: " + to_string((double)time / CLOCKS_PER_SEC) << endl;
        return num;
    }
};
```

Время выполнения для подбора 9999999: 10 секунд.
Этот же алгоритм, написанный на Java 9, выполнялся за 5 секунд. Код на Java привести не могу, но он такой же.

Comment: А вы выложите программы, скажем, на http://ideone.com/ - чтоб сравнить можно было... И расскажите, с какими ключиками компилируете, как в `getRight` строку передаете - может, вы ее по значению передаете, а не по ссылке... Вобщем, информации у вас практически никакой.

Comment: скинь код `getRight` я сейчас проверю оба варианта

Comment: В каком контексте располагается этот код? Что такое `getRight`? Без всего этого - вопрос бессмыслен.

Comment: Компилирую в jetBrains Clion с помощью cygwin

Comment: Ничего не менял как по стандарту было так и писал. Ничего кроме кода в вопросе по сути нет.. Только начал изучать c++ до этого занимался java.

Comment: А почему cygwin? Все же это почти что эмулятор..

Comment: Передача и возврат `string` по значению - это уже серьезное различие в семантике C++ и Java, которое может привести к заметным различиям в производительности. Другими словами, этот код делает существенно разные вещи в С++ и Java. С чего это вдруг вы решили, что один и тот же код имеет смысл компилировать и там и там и напрямую сравнивать?

Comment: Сокрее всего на выделении и копировании строк садится. Поменяйте на `bool getRight(const string & pass)`

Comment: Странный брутфорс: `от 1 до 10`, `от 1 до 100`, `от 1 до 1000`... зачем эти повторы?

Comment: не успел еще оптимизировать. на java разницы вообще не было.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А вот такой вариант в сишном стиле:

```
#include <cstdio>

string number_bruteforce()
{
    char buffer[32] = {0}; // - на стеке один раз создаем буферный массив 
                           //   из 32 символов (хватит для любого int)
                           //   и зануляем его весь 
    buffer[0] = '-';       // - установим нулевым символом `-`

    char * guess_signed   = &buffer[0]; // - получим указатель на элемент 0
                                        //   это будет срока "-q"
    char * guess_unsigned = &buffer[1]; // - получим указатель на элемент 1
                                        //   это будет срока "q"

    for (int i = 10; i < 100000000; i = i * 10) 
    {
        for (int q = 1; q < i; q++) 
        {
            // преобразуем q в строку
            std::snprintf
            (
                 guess_unsigned     // - строка запишется в буфер начиная 
                                    //   с элемента 1, в конце добавится 
                                    //   завершающий `\0`
               , sizeof(buffer) - 1 // - на всякий укажем размер буфера чтобы 
                                    //   не выйти за его пределы
               , "%d"               // - это форматная строка, говорит 
                                    //   что в буфер нужно писать число
               , q                  // - ну и само q передаем
            );

            if (getRight(guess_unsigned)) // для проверки передадим адрес на "q"
            {
               return guess_unsigned; // скопируем "q" в string и вернем его из функции
            }

            if (getRight(guess_signed)) // проверим "-q"
            {
               return guess_signed; // скопируем "-q" в string и вернем его из функции
            }
         } 
     }
}
```

И вот так:

```
bool getRight(const char * pass) 
{
    ++count;
    return password == pass;
}
```

Теперь по вашему вопросу, `std::string` выделяет память для строки в куче. Процесс выделения и освобождения памяти в куче занимает какое-то время, это же все системные вызовы. Здесь же мы создали буфер во-первых один раз, а во вторых на стеке. Ну и 32 байта на стеке вполне терпимо, это не 3 КБ как я выдел недавно.

Подсчитаем сколько раз ваш вариант обращается куче:

```
for (int i = 10; i < 100000000; i = i * 10) {
    for (int q = 1; q < i; q++) {
        string str = to_string(q); // 1 вызов : создаем и перемещаем в str
        if (getRight(str)) {       // 2 вызова: копируем str в pass и удаляем pass
            return str;
        }
        string n_str = "-" + str;  // 1 вызов : копируем str в n_str
        if (getRight(n_str)) {     // 2 вызова: копируем n_str в pass и удаляем pass
           return n_str;
        }
        // сюрприз, еще 2 вызова: удаляем str и n_str
   }
}
```

И того, на каждой итерации по 8 запросов к куче, вот от сюда ваши 10 секунд и вылазиют.

Comment: Если `pass` - это `std::string`, то  в строке `password == pass` произойдет неявное преобразование `password` к `std::string`, что негативно скажется на производительности.

Comment: @ВикторСмирнов Да нет, ничего не будет, для `std::string` есть перегрузка оператора сравнения для `const char *` http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp

Comment: Можете прокомментировать код.

Comment: Мне не очень понятно работа с символьными массивами.

Comment: @АЛЕКСЕЙФЕДЕЧКИН Добавил

Comment: Большое спасибо за пояснение

Answer (score 4):

Просто интереса ради собрал ваши фрагменты в нечто компилируемое - http://vpaste.net/2LpvX

Компилирую VC++ 2017. Без ключиков, по умолчанию. Время работы - 6.716с

Изменяю `bool getRight(string pass)` на `bool getRight(const string& pass)`, компилирую так же. 5.012с.

Компилирую с `/O2 /Ot`- время 0.462с.

Так что, как видите, без точного знания, что и как вы делали, можно получить все, что угодно...

Comment: Большое спасибо за советы.

Answer (score 3):

Очевидных причины две:

- Вы без причины копируете строку как минимум два раза (нужно передавать строку по константной ссылке)
- Вы используете `to_string`, который зависит от локалей и работает медленнее, чем мог бы, из-за нескольких косвенных вызовов. Это тот случай, когда JIT-компиляция JAVA реально имеет преимущество, т.к. если локаль не меняется, JIT-компилятор может оптимизировать лишние косвенные вызовы.

В остальном, результаты могут сильно зависеть от флагов компиляции и прочих условий тестирования.